# How to append one dict to dict and makes finally one

Tags: python

I have dictionary in python script like this

```
{key:value}
{key:value}
{key:value}
```

I wanted to make it into a single key dictionary like

```
[{'key':value} , {'key:value} , {'key':value}......]
```

My code is below:

```
for (recActorIMDBid, recActorName, recActorTopTen) in cursor:  

    recActorTopTen = str(recActorTopTen).replace(",", "_ ")
    contentIDArray =[]
    contentIDArray = recActorTopTen.split("_ ")
    if len(contentIDArray) > 9:

        stringOut = "ID," + str(recID) + ",IMDB ID," + str(recActorIMDBid) + ",NAME," + str(recActorName) + ",TOP TEN," \ + str(recActorTopTen)

        print(stringOut)
```

I need to change the result to json, what should I Do?

Comment: Your desired output is not a single key dictionary, but a list of single-keyed dictionaries. In order to achieve that create a list and append them to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
dict1 = {0: 5, 1: 8, 2: 3}
dict2 = {0: 6, 1: 2, 2: 4}
dict3 = {0: 7, 1: 9, 2: 2}
dicts = []
dicts.append(dict1)
dicts.append(dict2)
dicts.append(dict3)
```

Comment: how should be used Within for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over `items()` (key-value pairs) and use a list comprehension

```
[{k: v} for k, v in my_dict.items()]
```

Note: I'm assuming your question has a few typos, because what you describe is not exactly valid.

Comment: I am processing some data( like associative array  ) and return the response as JSON.

Comment: for (recActorIMDBid, recActorName, recActorTopTen) in cursor:
        
    recActorTopTen = str(recActorTopTen).replace(",", "_ ")
    contentIDArray =[]
    contentIDArray = recActorTopTen.split("_ ")
    if len(contentIDArray) > 9:

        stringOut = "ID," + str(recID) + ",IMDB ID," + str(recActorIMDBid) + ",NAME," + str(recActorName) + ",TOP TEN," \ + str(recActorTopTen)
        
        print(stringOut)

the above code returns string i need to change this format to json what should i do.

Comment: @AvzVicky: move the code into your question, it's unreadable here.

Comment: Added the code in question sections. my requirement was return response as json .